# Make eevee shadows darker?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shadows

Ok I’m trying to get darker, noticeable shadows in eevee, yet I’m barely getting anything, even with contact shadows on:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What can I change?

Comment: Please don't take photos of your display, those are very hard to read especially when picture quality is critical to solve the issue

Comment: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org should help with taking clearer screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually darken the shadow using a light path node.With or without HDRI lights..
You can adjust the darkness by increasing or decreasing the brightness value.... I don't know is there any better way to do this,but this will do the job![image]

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you! I did not even know one could boost the shadow pass that way. In my case though, I wish there was a way to increase the darkness of a shadow from a cutout image without increasing ALL the shadows in the image. In Cycles, placing a cutout will cast a proper dark shadow from a sun lamp, but in Eevee, the shadow gets washed out by the HDRI lighting. It's like shadows are NOT additive in Eevee, you can't add one shadow on another to make it darker, it just seems that all shadows add up to 1, which is unfortunate.

Comment: I ended up using the technique described at the thread below to render my main scene, plus a 2nd scene with a shadow pass and then composite in a third scene with a multiply node for the shadow. This was necessary because I was using a shadow catcher in Eevee and I did not want the cutout shadows getting darker on the ground, nor did I want dark shadows everywhere, only on a few objects. In a more basic setup, one could simply run a shadow pass in their current scene layer and Multiply that shadow pass in the compositor to get a darker shadow. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/150009/39431