# Compositing Blender

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am new to blender compositing and am trying to make the first picture look like the second one ( which is an imgur because it is too heavy. So my initial thoughts were: the 1st picture is too contrasted and over exposed and i need to make the whites a bit more yellowish without changing the grey floor. However i can't seem to dissociate the different elements of my scene !

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys, have a nice day [image]

[image]

Comment: You would have to share core of your scene to let us see your setup. Use https://blend-exchange.com ... Filmic is used in Color Management ... for yellow tint use yellowish light , grey floor is also yellowish so no need to separate

Comment: do you need to render the different objects and mix them together? check this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150009/how-to-render-multiple-scenes-at-once-composite-and-save-as-one-file-in-blende